# Can't the date and time of Quidditch matches change?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

In *The Prisoner of Azkaban*, Slytherin rearranged their match with Gryffindor due to their Seeker, Draco, being injured and Gryffindor played against Hufflepuff. Why didn't they rearrange the final match in *The Philosopher's Stone* to a date when their Seeker, Harry, would have recovered by?

Answer (score 9):

## It was the end of the school year - there wasn't enough time.

After his fight with Quirrell and the Dark Lord, Harry spends three days in a coma in the hospital wing.

> “How long have I been in here?’
>
> ‘Three days. Mr Ronald Weasley and Miss Granger will be most relieved you have come round, they have been extremely worried.’
> ‘But sir, the Stone –” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 17 (The Man with Two Faces)*</sup></sub>

There's not much time between him waking up and the end of the school year, so they couldn't have rescheduled the Quidditch match for when he could play.

> “After a good night’s sleep, Harry felt nearly back to normal.
> ‘I want to go to the feast,’ he told Madam Pomfrey as she straightened his many sweet-boxes. ‘I can, can’t I?” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 17 (The Man with Two Faces)*</sup></sub>

He's told to rest when he first wakes up, and the day after he wakes up is the day of the end-of-year feast, which Madam Pomfrey only reluctantly lets him go to.

> “Harry made his way down to the end-of-year feast alone that night. He had been held up by Madam Pomfrey’s fussing-about, insisting on giving him one last check-up, so the Great Hall was already full.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 17 (The Man with Two Faces)*</sup></sub>

Comment: Again in Prisoner of Azkaban when they won Quidditch cup there was so much time till the end of the semester.

Comment: Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban : Chapter 16 Professor Trelawney's Prediction: 
Harry's euphoria at finally winning the Quidditch Cup lasted at least a week. Even the weather seemed to be celebrating; as June approached, the days became cloudless and sultry, and all anybody felt like doing was strolling onto the grounds and flopping down on the grass with several pints of iced pumpkin juice, perhaps playing a casual game of Gobstones or watching the giant squid propel itself dreamily across the surface of the lake.

Comment: But they couldn't. Exams were nearly upon them, and instead of lazing around outside, the students were forced to remain inside the castle, trying to bully their brains into concentrating while enticing wafts of summer air drifted in through the windows.

Comment: Even exams haven't been started. Then how when Harrywas in the hospital for three days and Quidditch match was placed and school just ended?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is present within your question.

The rescheduled match was in the first round and so the dates of Gryffindor's matches with Slytherin and Hufflepuff were simply swapped. This wouldn't have been possible with the final match since there was no other match that it could be swapped with this since the school year had nearly ended.

Comment: Edited the last line to explain further. Bellatrix's answer is more on point than mine.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember the final match which took place in the first book while Harry was unconscious after his fight with Quirrell, which was 3 days. And when he woke up it was the day before the school was ending. So I don't think they had too many options to postpone the match since it was the last week of school. Also, nobody knew how long would Harry remain unconscious and will he be even fit enough to play once he wakes up(They were all afraid that he was not going to wake up). So there was not even any reason for Wood to postpone since he knew Harry wouldn't be able to play anyways.